# Speeding up get/post requests in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a lot of test code that makes requests, like so:

```
get 'user', :id => 1
response.code.should == "302"
```

These specs are slow because our server takes a while to respond. So sometimes it can take 2+seconds for a single spec to run. Is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Is that 2 seconds per test?  Or just 2 seconds to start up?  You should take a look at [Spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) and [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard)

Comment: 2 seconds per spec...there are about ~1000 specs, and some of them take 2sec+. We do use spork with guard when testing locally.